# how to close a pop up window on a web page using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, web, webdriver, driver

<Insert question here.>

```
public class Day4
{
    @Test
    public void main() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.get("http://live.guru99.com");
        Driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Mobile']"));
        element.click();
        element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='IPhone']/../../div[@class='actions']//a[text()='Add to Compare']"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.click();
        element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Samsung Galaxy']/../../div[@class='actions']//a[text()='Add to Compare']"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.click();
        element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Compare']"));
        element.click();
        element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Close Window']"));
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        element.click();
        Set<String> windowId = Driver.getWindowHandles(); // get window id of current window
        Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();

        String mainWinID = itererator.next();
        String newAdwinID = itererator.next();

        Driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
        System.out.println(Driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Driver.close();

        Driver.switchTo().window(mainWinID);
        System.out.println(Driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not a coding service. Please provide a succinct question. Also, WTF is this code dump? Don't code dump.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: ...and please format your code properly. It will help readability and make it more likely that people will answer your question.

Comment: AARRGGGHHHH... My eyes are bleeding.  Get rid of all those Thread.sleep()'s

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code and found that below element is not present

```
element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Close Window']"));
```

I have removed that code and now the pop-up working fine :--

```
 element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Compare']"));
 element.click();
 Set<String> windowId = Driver.getWindowHandles(); // get window id of current window
 Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();

 System.out.println(itererator);
 String mainWinID = itererator.next();
 String newAdwinID = itererator.next();

 Driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);

 Driver.close();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi Shubham,when i run the code it is showing as  Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@title='Close Window']"}
Command duration or timeout: 41 milliseconds.could u please check it once.

Comment: thats the same I said there is not element present as Close Window. please remove that element and click operation . if u remove that element the pop-up is opening and close sucessfully